# Swiper.js loop:true does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am trying to create carousel using swiper.js. 
Here is my configuration:

```
{
    slidesPerView: 1,
    slidesPerColumn: 1,
    initialSlide: this.initialSlide,
    loop: true
}
```

As expected, this will add duplicated slides, near first and last elements. And when I swipe from first to last element, it shows this duplicated blank slide, instead of last one.

As it seems, slides are duplicated incorrectly, because "src" attributes are removed from `<img>` tag, how to solve this?

You advices please?

P.S. I am using [ngx-swiper-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper) library for angular instead of swiper.js directly

[image]

Comment: for me, i use swiper.js a lot and i never faced the issues you mention. so please check or share your markup, i guess the error is somewhere in there..

Comment: The problem is that src attribute is removed from the duplicated (swiper adds duplicated slides to work properly while loop: true) <img> attribute

Comment: i know, i read your question. but since i never saw that behavior, i say the problem is not within swiper.js but in your markup. so please check, that your html is correct.. share it here and we can take a look..

Comment: I got it, but how is markup related to deleted src from <img> tags? I've manually updated duplicated slides, added src tags for images and carousel worked just fine. The problem is duplication. Ow and my bad, I will update the question, I am using ngx-swiper-wrapper for angular instead of swiper.js directly

Comment: if your markup is not correct, a browser might fix it on the fly, but javascript will not be that tolerant to errors.. so it might look good for the original element, but the clone gets corrupted. honestly, i'm guessing here, but as i said: you are not the first one to use that loop feature, so i would first scan your markup...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue when using swiper with React / NextJs.

My swiper is rendering elements (cards) each having an image, and a button with a certain inscription leading to a certain URL. When slides are not looped, they work fine. When `loop: true`, each slide gets the correct image but a URL from the next slide.

Answer (score -1):

according to docs :

```
{
    loop: true,
    initialSlide: 0, //this one accept a number according to docs
    slidesPerView: 1, //number or 'auto'
    slidesPerColumn: 1 //number
}
```